# CodeIgniter is discarding JOIN clause in SQL statement (Active Record)

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following function in one of my CI models:

```
function update_uu_feature($feature, $lang, $data) 
{
    $feature = str_replace('_', '-', $feature);
    $this->db->where('navigation', $feature);
    $this->db->where('language', $lang);
    $this->db->join('all_video_names', 'all_video_names.video_id = all_uu_features.video_id', 'inner');
    return $this->db->update('all_uu_features', $data);
}
```

But the “join” line gets discarded.  In the profiler, it outputs:

```
UPDATE `all_uu_features` SET `page_title` = 'Laser', `title` = 'Test', `keywords` = 'Test', `description` = 'Test', `feature_text` = '<p>Test text</p>', `learn_more_about` = 'Test Text 2', `overview` = 'test', `copy` = 'test' WHERE `navigation` = 'laser-interface' AND `language` = 'en'
```

Can someone help me with the syntax?  Thanks.  Most of the data is in the all_uu_features table, except for the video name, which is in the all_video_names table.  The two are joined on the video_id column in each table. In other words, all of the columns in the above statement are in all_uu_features except for video name.  Hope that's clear.

The SQL statement above shows the data is being returned in the post and being processed by the function, it's just not accepting the join for some reason.

Comment: What happens if you put the `join` before the `where`s?

Comment: Yeah, having just read the CI DB code it doesn't seem like it should make a difference. Just thought it might be worth a try, as that's the usual order in SQL statements. Wondering if maybe the CI Active Record stuff ignores JOINs with UPDATE statements all together...

Comment: Thanks.  You're right, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: And if you include `$this->db->from('all_video_names')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me very much like CI's Active Record class doesn't support using joins in its update() operation. Certainly if you have a look at the code (in DB_active_rec.php), the `update()` method doesn't even look at any joins that have been set up

From update():

```
$sql = $this->_update($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $this->ar_set, $this->ar_where, $this->ar_orderby, $this->ar_limit);
```

Comment: Well that's stupid.  So you can only update one table at a time?

Comment: @shummel7845 Traditionally, SQL databases only let you update one table at a time, which I'm guessing would be the reason for this limitation in CI.